# How to control routing for protected pages in React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Do I need check auth in every protected page container and if it false redirect to login page? what can i do if i have a lot of protected pages?

Comment: You can make use of Hight Order Component, https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Higher order component (HOC) for your router. use a PrivateRouter hoc.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)
```

use this instead of route.

```
<PrivateRoute component={component} {...props} />
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nisfan said, making a HOC is not a bad idea.

For example:

```
// This HOC redirects to the landing page if user isn't logged in.
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LANDING } from '../constants/routes';

const ERROR_MESSAGE = 'You need to be logged in to access that page.';

const withAuthentication = (condition, route = LANDING) => (Component) => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if (!condition(this.props.userState.loggedIn)) {
        this.props.history.push(route);
        // TODO: show error if you want
      }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.userState.loggedIn !== this.props.userState.loggedIn) {
        if (!condition(nextProps.userState.loggedIn)) {
          this.props.history.push(route);
          // TODO: show error if you want
        }
      }
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.userState.loggedIn ? <Component /> : null;
    }
  }

  WithAuthentication.propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    userState: PropTypes.object,
  };

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userState: state.userState,
  });

  const temp = connect(mapStateToProps)(WithAuthentication);

  return withRouter(temp);
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

Then, when you want to protect a route, you can wrap your component in `withAuthentication` with a condition.

For example, your condition could be whether or not the user is signed in, or whether or not the user is signed in and is an admin, etc.